# Android Fragment Data Loading in recycler

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have a ProductListActivity which contains viewpager and tablayout. I am setting adapter of viewpager that is FragmentProductCategory. In FragmentCategoryAdapter constructor, passing context and CategoryList refrence. CategoryList is simple pojo class which contains categoryId & categoryName. In FragmentCategoryAdapter constructor, using for loop I am creating ProductList (another pojo class which contains product related info) ArrayList() instances and storing it in again another instance of CategoryList class with another constructor of it.
Now from getItem() of FragmentCategoryAdapter  i am creating TabFragment using newInstance() method of it and passing refrence of ProductList instance as per its position. In TabFragment class, it contains recyclerview and I am calling asycntask to get productlist from server.     I am properly getting data in onPostExecute. and then passing it into fragment using ProductListNotifyListener onTaskCompleted() method and setting recyclerview adapter here. 
But on opening ProductListActivity first tab never shows data on its loading. And second issue is on swiping fragments tab data are exchanging. 
I am not getting what I am doing wrong here. Please help me. And please also tell me am I doing all these process in a standard way or not? Is there any other way of doing it?
I am posting my files code.

This is ProductListActivity.java class

```
public class ProductListActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
            private List<CategoryList> categoryLists;
            private static Context context;
            private TabLayout tabLayout;
            private ViewPager viewPager;
            public static FragmentProductCategory categoryAdapter;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);

                context = ProductListActivity.this;

                /* Get category list from SharedPreferences */
                categoryLists = new AppSharedPreference(this).getCategoryLists();

               /* Setting up toolbar */
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

                /* Displaying home page back button enabled */
                ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                if(actionBar!=null){
                    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                    //actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_back_arrow));
                   /* Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_back_arrow);
                    if(drawable!=null){
                        int color = Color.parseColor("#535353");
                        drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    }*/
                    TextView textView = (TextView)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.titleToolbar);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#535353"));

                }


                /* Setting tabs and titles as per no of categries */
                /* Getting UI element's reference */
                viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerProductList);
                tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tlProductList);

                /*Creating fragment adapter class for tabs and setting it in viewpager */
                categoryAdapter = new FragmentProductCategory(getSupportFragmentManager(),categoryLists,this);
                viewPager.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);

                /*Setting up tab layout with view pager and other effects*/
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
                tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
                tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                tabLayout.setTabTextColors(R.color.colorPrimary, R.color.colorPrimary);
                tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
                tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(6);
                tabLayout.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);


                /* Fetching intent data send from home activity and as per data get setting that particular tab */
                String categoryId = getIntent().getStringExtra("category-id");
                if(categoryId!=null){
                    int pos=0;
                    /* Looping through categoryList and matching categoryId received from intent to categoryList
                    *  and on the basis of that fetching position of that particular tab
                    * */
                    for (int i=0;i<categoryLists.size();i++){
                        if(categoryLists.get(i).getCategoryId().equals(categoryId)){
                            // Log.d("cat-id111", categoryLists.get(i).getCategoryId() + "\n pos=" + pos);
                            pos=i;
                        }
                    }
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
                }

                /** Getting product list from server as per
                 * category-id from other pages has get or
                 * by default load data for first tab category id
                 **/
                if(categoryId==null){
                    categoryId = categoryLists.get(0).getCategoryId();
                }


            }
        }
```

This is ProductList.java simple pojo class to store product list info.

```
public class ProductList {
            public String getCategoryId() {
                return categoryId;
            }

            public String getProductId() {
                return productId;
            }

            public String getProductName() {
                return productName;
            }

            public String getProductDetails() {
                return productDetails;
            }

            public String getProductPrice() {
                return productPrice;
            }

            public String getProductBarcode() {
                return productBarcode;
            }

            public String getStockQuantity() {
                return stockQuantity;
            }

            public String getOfferName() {
                return offerName;
            }

            public String getOfferPrice() {
                return offerPrice;
            }

            public String getThumb() {
                return thumb;
            }

            public String getBanner() {
                return banner;
            }

            public String getProductSize() {
                return productSize;
            }

            public void setProductSize(String productSize) {
                this.productSize = productSize;
            }

            public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
                this.categoryId = categoryId;
            }

            public void setProductId(String productId) {
                this.productId = productId;
            }

            public void setProductName(String productName) {
                this.productName = productName;
            }

            public void setProductDetails(String productDetails) {
                this.productDetails = productDetails;
            }

            public void setProductPrice(String productPrice) {
                this.productPrice = productPrice;
            }

            public void setProductBarcode(String productBarcode) {
                this.productBarcode = productBarcode;
            }

            public void setStockQuantity(String stockQuantity) {
                this.stockQuantity = stockQuantity;
            }

            public void setOfferName(String offerName) {
                this.offerName = offerName;
            }

            public void setOfferPrice(String offerPrice) {
                this.offerPrice = offerPrice;
            }

            public void setThumb(String thumb) {
                this.thumb = thumb;
            }

            public void setBanner(String banner) {
                this.banner = banner;
            }

            public ArrayList<String> getBannerList() {
                return bannerList;
            }

            public ArrayList<ProductContentList> getContentList() {
                return contentList;
            }

            public String categoryId;
            public String productId;
            public String productName;
            public String productDetails;
            public String productPrice;
            public String productBarcode;
            public String productSize;
            public String stockQuantity;
            public String offerName;
            public String offerPrice;
            public String thumb;
            public String banner;
            private ArrayList<String> bannerList;
            private ArrayList<ProductContentList> contentList;

            public ProductList(HashMap<String,String> hashMap){
                this.categoryId=hashMap.get("categoryId");
                this.productId=hashMap.get("productId");
                this.productName=hashMap.get("productName");
                this.productDetails=hashMap.get("productDetails");
                this.productPrice=hashMap.get("productPrice");
                this.productBarcode=hashMap.get("productBarcode");
                this.productSize=hashMap.get("productSize");
                this.stockQuantity=hashMap.get("stockQuantity");
                this.offerName=hashMap.get("offerName");
                this.offerPrice=hashMap.get("offerPrice");
                this.thumb=hashMap.get("productImageLink");
                prepareBannersAndContents(hashMap.get("bannerImageLinks"),hashMap.get("contentDetails"));
            }

            private void prepareBannersAndContents(String bannerLinks,String contentDetails){
                try {
                    JSONArray pBannerArr = new JSONArray(bannerLinks);
                    bannerList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int j=0;j<pBannerArr.length();j++){
                        bannerList.add(j,pBannerArr.getJSONObject(j).getString("imageLink"));
                    }
                    JSONArray pDetailsArr = new JSONArray(contentDetails);
                    contentList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int j=0;j<pDetailsArr.length();j++){
                        JSONObject object = pDetailsArr.getJSONObject(j);
                        contentList.add(new ProductContentList(object.getString("quantity"),object.getString("iconLink")));
                    }
                }catch (JSONException | NullPointerException jse){
                    jse.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

This is FragmentProductCategory.java viewpager adapter.

```
public class FragmentProductCategory extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
        private int PAGE_COUNT;
        private List<CategoryList> catList;
        public static List<CategoryList> dataList;

        public FragmentProductCategory(FragmentManager fragmentManager1, List<CategoryList> catList, Context context1){
            super(fragmentManager1);
            this.catList=catList;
            this.PAGE_COUNT = catList.size();
            dataList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i=0;i<catList.size();i++){
                List<ProductList> pList = new ArrayList<>();
                dataList.add(new CategoryList(catList.get(i).getCategoryId(), catList.get(i).getCategoryName(), pList));
                Log.d("ProductListTest",""+i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position){
            Log.d("ProductListTest","getItem"+position);
            return TabFragment.newInstance(position, dataList.get(position).getCategoryId(), dataList.get(position).getCategoryName());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return catList.get(position).getCategoryName();
        }

        public void applyFilters(int pos){
            //tabFragment1.applyFilterSortSizeOperations(pos);
        }

        public static class TabFragment extends Fragment implements ProductListNotifyListener{
            private ProgressBar progressBar;
            private LinearLayout llNoData;
            private TextView tvNoDataMsg;
            private Button btnTryAgain;
            private Context context;
            private RecyclerView recyclerView;
            private ProductListAdapter productAdapter;

            // on scroll
            private static int fromIndex = 0,loadLimit = 20;


            private int pagePosition;
            private String catId,catName;
            private static TabFragment fragment;

            public static TabFragment newInstance(int position,String catId,String catName) {
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("position", position);
                args.putString("id", catId);
                args.putString("name", catName);
                fragment = new TabFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                pagePosition = getArguments().getInt("position");
                catId = getArguments().getString("id");
                catName = getArguments().getString("name");
                context = getContext();
            }

            @Nullable
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_category,container,false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
                progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvProductCategory);
                llNoData = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.llNoData);
                tvNoDataMsg = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvNoDataMsg);
                btnTryAgain = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnTryAgain);

                tvNoDataMsg.setTypeface(new SetFonts(context).setSourceSansProRegularFonts(), Typeface.ITALIC);
                GridLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ItemOffsetDecoration(getContext(), R.dimen.item_offset_inner));

                //new SoapClient(context).getProductList(catId, fromIndex, loadLimit, productLists, listAdditionalArgs, recyclerView, llNoData, progressBar,fragment,productAdapter);
                final ArrayList<String> listAdditionalArgs = new ArrayList<>();
                listAdditionalArgs.add(ProductListActivity.appliedProductSize);
                listAdditionalArgs.add(ProductListActivity.appliedSort);
                listAdditionalArgs.add(ProductListActivity.appliedMaxPrice);
                listAdditionalArgs.add(ProductListActivity.appliedMinPrice);
                new SoapClient(context).getProductListTest(catId,pagePosition, fromIndex, loadLimit, listAdditionalArgs,fragment,recyclerView,llNoData,progressBar);
                recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new ProductListScrollListener(linearLayoutManager, "",context) {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadMore(String current_page_id, int fromIndex) {
                        //loadMoreData(current_page_id, productLists, fromIndex);
                    }
                });

                btnTryAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        llNoData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        // new SoapClient(context).getProductList(catId, fromIndex, loadLimit, productLists, listAdditionalArgs, recyclerView,llNoData,progressBar);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResume() {
                super.onResume();
                ProductListActivity.resetCartViewText();
                //FragmentProductCategory.productAdapter.notifyData();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTaskStart(RecyclerView recyclerView1,LinearLayout llNoData1,ProgressBar progressBar1) {
                llNoData1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recyclerView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(int position, String response) {
                Log.d("ProductListTest","onTaskCompleted"+position);
                List<ProductList> pList = dataList.get(position).getProductLists();
                try {
                    pList.clear();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        HashMap<String,String> hashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap1.put("productId",jsonObject1.getString("productId"));
                        hashMap1.put("productName", jsonObject1.getString("productName"));
                        hashMap1.put("productDetails", jsonObject1.getString("productDetails"));
                        hashMap1.put("productPrice", jsonObject1.getString("productPrice"));
                        hashMap1.put("productBarcode", jsonObject1.getString("productBarcode"));
                        hashMap1.put("productSize", jsonObject1.getString("productSize"));
                        hashMap1.put("stockQuantity", jsonObject1.getString("stockQuantity"));
                        hashMap1.put("offerName", jsonObject1.getString("offerName"));
                        hashMap1.put("offerPrice", jsonObject1.getString("offerPrice"));
                        hashMap1.put("productImageLink", jsonObject1.getString("productImageLink"));
                        hashMap1.put("bannerImageLinks", jsonObject1.getString("bannerImageLinks"));
                        hashMap1.put("contentDetails", jsonObject1.getString("contentDetails"));
                        pList.add(new ProductList(hashMap1));
                    }
                    productAdapter = new ProductListAdapter(pList,context);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(productAdapter);
                    productAdapter.notifyData();
                    dataList.get(position).setProductLists(pList);
                }catch (JSONException jse){
                    jse.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onException() {
                llNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is CategoryList.java, a simple pojo class to store category list info and ProductList instance references.

```
public class CategoryList {
    private String categoryId,categoryName;
    private List<ProductList> productLists;
    private ProductListAdapter productListAdapter;
    public CategoryList(String categoryId,String categoryName){
        this.categoryId=categoryId;
        this.categoryName=categoryName;
    }

    public CategoryList(String categoryId,String categoryName,List<ProductList> productLists){
        this.categoryId=categoryId;
        this.categoryName=categoryName;
        this.productLists=productLists;
    }

    public String getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public List<ProductList> getProductLists() {
        return productLists;
    }

    public void setProductLists(List<ProductList> productLists) {
        this.productLists = productLists;
    }
}
```

This is ProductListNotifyListener.java interface which is implemented in TabFragment.java class

```
public interface ProductListNotifyListener {
    public void onTaskStart(RecyclerView recyclerView,LinearLayout llNoData,ProgressBar progressBar);
    public void onTaskCompleted(int position,String response);
    public void onException();
}
```

This is ProductListAdapter.java which is used to display data in recylerview

```
public class ProductListAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductListAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
    public static List<ProductList> productLists;
    private Context context;
    private SetFonts setFonts;
    private AppSharedPreference sharedPreference;
    public  AlertDialog alertDialogProductDetails;
    public  int productDetailsPosition;

    public ProductListAdapter(){}

    public ProductListAdapter(List<ProductList> productLists,Context context){
        this.productLists=productLists;
        this.context=context;
        sharedPreference = new AppSharedPreference(context);

        /* Getting reference of SetFont class */
        setFonts = new SetFonts(context);
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tvProductName,tvProductPrice,tvPriceSymbol;
        ImageView ivProductThumb,ivInformation,ivCart;

        public MyViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            ivProductThumb = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivProductThumb);
            ivInformation = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivInformation);
            ivCart = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivCart);
            tvProductName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
            tvProductPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvProductPrice);
            tvPriceSymbol = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvPriceSymbol);

            /* Applying custom fonts */
            tvProductName.setTypeface(setFonts.setSourceSansProSemiboldFonts());
            tvProductPrice.setTypeface(setFonts.setSourceSansProRegularFonts());



        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_product_list,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {
            if(sharedPreference.isProductAddedInCart(productLists.get(position).getProductId())){
                holder.ivCart.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_cart_added));
            }else {
                holder.ivCart.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_cart));
            }
            /* JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(productLists.get(position).getThumb());
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);*/
            String imageLink = productLists.get(position).getThumb();
            Glide.with(context).load(imageLink).thumbnail(0.5f).animate(R.anim.fade_in).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).placeholder(R.drawable.img_placeholder_1x1).into(holder.ivProductThumb);
            holder.tvProductName.setText(productLists.get(position).getProductName());
            holder.tvProductPrice.setText(productLists.get(position).getProductPrice());
        }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | NullPointerException  jse){
            jse.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(productLists.size()>0){
          return productLists.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }



    public void notifyData(){
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

Comment: Please provide your all design (.xml) so i can elaborate it.\ and also give AppSharedPreference, SetFonts, ProductContentList file.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I have solved my issue. And posted my answer. But thank you for giving your valuable time in reading my post. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have sorted my issues the day before yesterday. In ProductListActivity class I have declared List productLists as static that was causing problem. I removed static keyword and problem is solved.